# R Shiny renderDataTable issue

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

When I try the following code in R, The Data Table renders perfectly with the different numbers of "x" buttons in Button Column.

```
data <- iris[1:20,1:2]
data$Button <- lapply(paste0("x",1:20),function(x) paste(rep(as.character(actionButton(x,label="x")),sample(1:3,1)),collapse="  ",sep="  "))
datatable(data)
```

But when I try to wrap the data frame in the shiny app, There are always the same number of "x" buttons in every row on one page. Reproducible Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytab <- renderDataTable({
data <- iris[1:20,1:2]
data$Button <- lapply(paste0("x",1:20),function(x) paste(rep(as.character(actionButton(x,label="x")),sample(1:3,1)),collapse="  ",sep="  "))
datatable(data)
})
}
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
),
mainPanel(dataTableOutput("mytab"))
)
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the following error pops up.

```
Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = list("<button id=\"x1\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default action-button\">x</button>",  :
provided 10 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Any suggestion on how can I fix that?

```
System Information
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
[1] DT_0.2.12   shiny_1.0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was your button IDs:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")
set.seed(1)

data <- iris[1:20, 1:2]
data$Button <- sapply(paste0("x", 1:20), function(x) {
  n_seq <- seq(sample(1:3, 1L))
  btns  <- sapply(n_seq, function(n) {
    id <- sprintf("%s_%s", x, n)
    as.character(actionButton(id, label = "x"))
  })
  return(paste0(btns, collapse = "  "))
})

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data, escape = FALSE)
  })
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("mytab"))
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I am having the exact same error and issue when I try to run your code. These are my package versions DT_0.2.12   shiny_1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring the fixed code to original code format after taking suggestions from @mlegge's answer

1) Replaced the lapply call with sapply call in line6

2) Added escape=FALSE parameter to datatable call in line 7

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytab <- renderDataTable({
data <- iris[1:20,1:2]
data$Button <- sapply(paste0("x",1:20),function(x) paste(rep(as.character(actionButton(x,label="x")),sample(1:3,1)),collapse="  ",sep="  "))
datatable(data,escape=FALSE)
})
}
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
),
mainPanel(dataTableOutput("mytab"))
)
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```