# Shiny error: provided 10 variables to replace 1 variables

Tags: shiny

Unfortunately I can't use my actual data.frame since it is not mine and is copyrighted, but I will try to explain as best as I can

I have a data.frame that contains a column with unique strings.
when I do datatable(mydf) in the Rstudio console, it shows me the correct table in viewer. However, when I do the same in shiny I get this warning:

Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = list("ECDTM-12 Trimmed eTAG truncated after Fn F232C No Stop CRLF2 transcript variant 1 NM_022148_3",  :
provided 10 variables to replace 1 variables

essentially what it does is it takes the first string in that column "ECDTM-12 Trimmed eTAG truncated after Fn F232C No Stop CRLF2 transcript variant 1 NM_022148_3" and overrides every other string in that row with this string, instead of showing what those rows actually contain

some maybe helpful code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(xlsx)
library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(ggthemes)
library(DT)
set.seed(1)
```

code in the UI function:

```
fluidRow(column(12, align="center", withSpinner(dataTableOutput("partTables")
```

code in the server function:

```
Lib_P1_P2 <- reactive(if(LibName() == "1.1A" | LibName() == "1.1B" | LibName() == "2.1"){readRDS(paste0("data/",input$library," P1_P2.rds"))})    
output$partTables <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(Lib_P1_P2(),options=list(pagelength=10), rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE) 
})
```

I added set.seed(1) and escape=FALSE after I saw this question:
[R Shiny renderDataTable issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875943/r-shiny-renderdatatable-issue) but that didn't work either..

If I've left out any important info, let me know I'd be happy to provide.
I'm new to stackoverflow so excuse my newbie-ness.

Comment: Try having `renderDataTable()` return your data.frame directly, rather than passing it through `Datatable` first. The [shiny example of integrating with data tables](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html) does this.

Comment: that shows me the right table, with the right rows now, but the reason I was using datatable was for the options, like having the pagelength set to 10... so you think the problem is the way datatable is reading my data.frame?

Comment: Replace `renderDataTable` with `DT::renderDataTable` and `dataTableOutput` with `DT::dataTableOutput` to make sure the correct namespace is used. These functions also exist in the `shiny` package

Comment: Adding DT:: caused my rows to be the same again

Comment: What do you mean "the same again"? `DT::renderDataTable({datatable(...)})` should give you almost the same table as in the RStudio console.

Comment: It isn't, its taking the first string it reads "ECDTM-12 Trimmed eTAG truncated after Fn F232C No Stop CRLF2 transcript variant 1 NM_022148_3" and replacing the rest of the rows with it, so that this whole column now only contains this string, this only happens when I use datatable on my data.frame, I know the data.frame contains the correct rows

Comment: well I found a workaround, but not a solution.. I was able to take out the column and convert it to a dataframe on its own, then cbind it back onto my original dataframe and then use datatable on the new dataframe... and it's showing the right stings in the rows now

Comment: I figured out the reason!! The whole table was a dataframe except for that last column which was apparently a list, I had unlist it and it worked after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the reason!! The whole table was a dataframe except for that last column which was apparently a list, I had to unlist it and it worked after that